# Exercises in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I'm always having problem with this type of question : 1). Can the set ${1,2,...,2010}$ be expressed as the disjoint union of $A_{1},A_{2},...,A_{n}$ such that 
a). Each $A_{i}$ contains the same number of elements and 
b). The sum of all elements of each $A_{i}$  is the same for $i=1,2,...,n$.

2). Prove that the set ${1,2,...,2011}$ cannot be expressed as the disjoint union of $A_{1},A_{2},...,A_{n}$  such that 
a). Each $A_{i}$ contains the same number of elements and 
b). The sum of all elements of each $A_{i}$ is the same for $i=1,2,...,n$

3). Can the set ${1,2,3,...,25}$ be arranged in 14 distinct representation as follows; $A_{i}$, if $2\le i \le 5$ and $B_{j}$, $6\le i \le 15$ such that 1). $A_{i}$ has 3 disjoint cycles with 5 elements in each and 2). $B_{j}$ has 5 disjoint cycles with 3 elements in each.

I always have problem with questions like those ones above, If I can understand these questions and I'm able to solve it, then I hope I  will be able to do the rest that is in my joting notes.  Thanks!

Comment: Where do cycles come from in 3)?

Comment: In the first two questions is the value of $n$ imposed? If so, what is it? If not, I would choose $n=1$, which shows the second point is false.

Comment: Point 3) is quite incomprehensible. What's a representation here, to begin with?

Comment: @Marc, $i$ ranges from $1,...,n$. According to the question here, the value of $i$ is not imposed.

Comment: @Hagen, question 3 is another question entirely

Comment: @user143681: I was asking about $n$, not about $i$. And please, take a minute to reread what you wrote yourself with the eyes of a stranger; you will find there is much there that is really not clear. And when answering to a comment, try to understand the comment and answer to what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

1) is easy: $1+2010=2+2009=3+2008=\ldots$.

2) is possible if we allow $n=1$. Since $2011$ is prime the only alternative candidate for $n$ is $2011$ itself, which doesn't work.

Comment: Pls, I'll be glad if I you can explain in detail, because I want to understand it, not just for me to know the answer. It maybe simple but I'm not really getting it.  Thanks!